# How do I get karma to set webpack's mode to development?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, webpack, jasmine, karma-runner

When I run karma, I'm getting the following warning:

> WARNING in configuration
>   The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
>   You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

I tried adding `mode: 'development'` to my `webpack-test.config.js` file as suggested in the link above, but not only did that fail to make any difference, Intellij IDEA complained:

> webpack: Property 'mode' is not allowed

My unit testing does run anyway, but I'd like to get rid of this warning. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's my `webpack-test.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const ROOT = path.resolve( __dirname, 'src' );

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  context: ROOT,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    modules: [
      ROOT,
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      // PRE-LOADERS
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'source-map-loader'
      },

      // LOADERS
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: [ /node_modules/ ],
        use: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  devServer: {}
};
```

My `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-webpack')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    files: [
      'spec.bundle.js'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'spec.bundle.js': ['webpack']
    },
    webpack: require('./webpack-test.config')
  });
};
```

And `spec.bundle.js`:

```
const testsContext = require.context("./", true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext);
```

I'm launching karma via:

```
karma start ./karma.conf.js
```

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled on this by trial and error, replacing:

```
webpack: require('./webpack-test.config')
```

...in `karma.conf.js` with:

```
webpack: {
  mode: 'development'
}
```

...and the warning is gone. Not only that, I discovered that I really didn't need my `webpack-test.config`, nor the two npm modules I'd loaded to support it, `source-map-loader` and `ts-loader`.

If someone really did want to both specify `mode: 'development'` and specify a particular webpack config file, I'm not sure how they'd do it. I experimented with a few options and couldn't find anything that would work. This stuff doesn't have great documentation :(

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to require the webpack package in your config file.  Not sure if that is causing Intellij to get confused or not, but `mode` is certainly a valid property of webpack.

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

I also noticed that in your `karma.conf.js` file, the line `webpack: require('./webpack-test.config')` is missing the `.js` extension for the config file.  That may be why your config settings are not reflected in your karma test.